# .htaccess and how to set RewriteEngine correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I own these 4 domains:

```
-example.it
-www.example.it
-example.com
-www.example.com
```

I want them all to 301 redirect to www.example.com. I'm currently running Apache2 on Ubuntu.

What is the correct syntax for my .htaccess file?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following RewriteRule in your htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?(example\.com|example\.it)$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Short explaination :

The first RewriteCond excludes the destination domain **www.example.com** We have excluded it to avoid the Redirect loop error. The second condition matches either **www.example.it** , **example.com** or **example.it** and then the rule redirects the request to **www.example.com** .